# Como arrumar a ordem da data?

Tags: php, mysql

No banco de dados:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mostrando na página (em php):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria que ela aparecesse da seguinte maneira: 03-11-2015

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strtotime.php), assim:

```
$data = "2010-01-02";
echo date("d-m-Y",strtotime($data));
// Saída: 02-01-2010
```

Veja no [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/kUfbl3).

Answer (score 1):

Você poderia fazer da seguinte forma usando a classe DateTime:

```
<?php

$data = '2015-11-01';

$date = new DateTime($data);
echo $date->format('d-m-Y');//01-11-2015
```

Ou também usando expressão regular:

```
$pattern = '/^([[:digit:]]{4})-([[:digit:]]{2})-([[:digit:]]{2})$/';
$replacement = '$3-$2-$1';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $data);//01-11-2015
```

Ou também outra forma poderia ser usando funções de manipulação de array e string:

```
$parts = array_reverse(explode('-', $data));
echo implode('-', $parts);//01-11-2015
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar essa função que eu fiz pro meu site:

```
<?php
   function data($data){
      $f = explode("-", $data); //Gera um array com 0 = ano, 1 = mês, 2 = dia
      $g = $f[2]."/".$f[1]."/".$f[0]; //Isso é uma string. Formate-a como quiser
      return $g;
   }
?>
```

Você pode usar ela pra hora também, mudando o parâmetro do explode de `"-"` para `":"`.